# Is there way to convert docx to image-only pdf with convertapi?

Tags: pdf, docx, convertapi

I'm trying to find a way to convert docx to image-only pdf, so I could put a watermark on the pdf document right after conversion.

I've looked through convertapi documentation and I can't find any available options.

Comment: Convert to image or pdf? Not clear from the question.

Comment: Convert docx to image-only pdf, like the one you get when you print your docx to a file.

Comment: I am not sure why you need image-only pdf but you can put Watermark on any PDF using ConvertAPI watermark rest api https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-watermark
What programming language do you use? I would send you example.

Comment: @Tomas thank you! I'm already using https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS to do the watermark part internally without making another API request. So far I have to convert docx to pdf and pdf to image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the `.docx` file to a `.jpg`:

https://www.convertapi.com/docx-to-jpg

then feed the `.jpg` to

https://www.convertapi.com/jpg-to-pdf

to generate `.pdf`

You can chain the API calls to get your desired output.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to find a way to do the conversion in one API call

Comment: Even if it exists, it would probably do the same thing internally as above.

Comment: The ConvertAPI chaining will not use any resources on your side, you do chain action internally without downloading file and re-uploading it.

Comment: @Tomas didn't know that there was this chaining feature. That's the perfect solution!